# What's wrong with using Inheritance Equality in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, equals

In the book "*Core Java Volume 1*" that I am reading it says the equality shouldn't work with inheritance. So, I have the following example which seems to have something wrong going on:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        C c = new C("Test", 10);
        D d = new D("Test", 10);

        if (c.equals(d))
            System.out.println("Equal");
        else
            System.out.println("Unequal");

        if (d.equals(c))
            System.out.println("Equal");
        else
            System.out.println("Unequal");
    }
}


class C
{
    C(String cstr, int cnum) {
        str = cstr;
        num = cnum;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object otherObject) {

        // A quick test to see if the objects are identical.
        if (this == otherObject) {
            return true;
        }

        // Must return false if the explicit parameter is null
        if (otherObject == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (!(otherObject instanceof C))
            return false;

        // Now we know otherObject is a non-null Employee
        C other = (C) otherObject;

        // Test whether the fields have identical values
        return str.equals(other.str) && num == other.num;
    }

    private String str;
    private int num;
}

class D extends C {

    D(String cstr, int cnum) {
        super(cstr, cnum);
    }
}
```

http://ideone.com/PhFBwG

It returns "Equal" for both symmetrical comparisons which presumably it shouldn't. Is it missing another `equals` method in derived class 'D'? If so then what could wrong with above sample code if I don't use another `equals` in derived it at all?

Comment: "// Now we know otherObject is a non-null Employee"  - should be -  Now we know otherObject is a non-null Employee or a non-null subclass of Employee.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That code works because, as you said, `D` doesn't override `equals`. I expect the point the book is making is that `D` **should** override `equals` (and they should both override `hashCode`), because a `D` instance shouldn't be equal to a `C` instance, as they're different (albeit related) types.

Remember that one of the key aspects of [the `equals` contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) is *symmetry*. For any non-`null` values of `c` and `d`, if `c.equals(d)` is true, then `d.equals(c)` must be true (and the converse). While that's true in your current code, it probably shouldn't be, because `D` and `C` are different types. If a `D` instance is truly *equivalent* to a `C` instance, why have `D`?

Answer (score 4):

If you want instances `C` and `D` to not compare as equal replace `!(otherObject instanceof C)` with `otherObject.getClass() != this.getClass()`. This would ensure that only a `C` could ever be equal to another `C` and only a `D` could ever be equal to another `D`.

Whether or not that's what you want depends on a few factors. My general rule of thumb is that it's a bad idea to have an "open-ended" equality class where "external users" (whatever that means for you) can add to it. If you want objects of different types to compare as equal (and that's rare enough), then the hierarchy should be strictly controlled (with `final` classes, for example).

Collections (and similar well-defined interfaces) are different: here the interface defines a very precise contract that all implementing classes need to follow (i.e. an `ArrayList` can be equal to a `LinkedList` if they both contain the same elements in the same order, because the `List` interface defines what it means for two `List`s to be equal).